# how to address this security breach in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am using OAuth token based authentication in my web api based project.

If user is authenticated,an access token is generated as below.

```
{"access_token":"FFz_DC6zzEDD4mGOCk9172ijj3sGxCUWnk-tGanm9wGk76hMB8sHI8ImeWtdUKHHGNXv465ZSlbb-3fr_hr9DqUHc9Dm9OBI7XjJhdjdOpAGAGSFOpE0Y17LCEWTjCmEZotuf42Mpgl81ewoS7OlnH4b5w4PrtzJbIBpSAMoWObziL_U3mTkeFKvWrcWOfvlSCvhhBA9Dc3UTXv3HiHKWQk0T3-pvVy7ZuW2oac-IIuaq_GYaVkIZh7s9-YjX9KAL2Z9yfrPrVOQXZe_5OcNd7nS3tdT5odchEAiuWRYQ6t7Tfb2si4T6VdAe73OYefE0se1FeQsxbOiNaLyF8OwBqymEUzEG8tEHJ-cejVbhPw","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1799,"as:client_id":"","user":"1","role":"1",".issued":"Thu, 16 Feb 2017 09:37:44 GMT",".expires":"Thu, 16 Feb 2017 10:07:44 GMT"}
```

Below is one of the api method.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{userId}/{type}/")]
    public IHttpResponse GetCustomerDetails(int userId, string type)
    {
       //my api stuff
    }
```

I am using Postman for testing api. When I pass parameters as

```
http://localhost:50684/api/customer/1/gold
--along the access token in token in header--
```

It returns the desired json.

But if I use the same token & pass the customer id = 2,still it allows the access to the other customer(with id=2).

```
 http://localhost:50684/api/customer/2/gold
 --Access token in header--
```

It should NOT allow to access the resource to user with id=2 since the generated access token is valid for user with id =1.

How do I prevent this security breach?

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Its because u are not keeping your `Tokens` within a database and assign it to each user. you have to compare the token with the only which got generated and send to database for safe keeping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you send the userId as a parameter which by itself is bad design.

The simple solution is to get the current user from the context instead

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("{type}/")]
public IHttpResponse GetCustomerDetails(string type)
{
    var user = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
   //my api stuff
}
```

Comment: Wow!! This is the stuff I was looking for. A biggggggggggg thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store user id and token in some storage(session, db). 
And write own [MVC authorization fileter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) like `Authorize` filter, which compare token with user id stored in storage.

Answer (score 0):

Currently WebApi doesn't match the concept of user id and authenticated user's id. And it shouldn't, because the only thing you specify is the route of the controller's method with some parameter. You only require the user to be authenticated, by using "Authorize" attribute, but once the access is granted, no further validation is run. To make this method available to only specific subset of your users you could either write your own generic validation (i.e. in this case check against the claims of the user which can be accessed by "User" property within controller scope, or use some out-of-the-box external implementations of handling authentication.